# How to reduce the annoying sound of falling raindrops on a tent?

Tags: camping, tents

Every time I go camping and it starts to rain, I can't sleep anymore because the raindrops that fall on the tent causes a really loud and annoying sound. Is there any technique or tool to avoid or at least decrease that sound?

Comment: Awww man, I think the sound of rain on the tent is one of the greatest things ever :)

Comment: It may sound simple, but - earmuffs?

Comment: @whatsisname it's the most annoying thing, expect maybe drunk neighbors or close airports.

Comment: I think it's something one can get used to. But if not, earplugs are the natural solution.

Comment: Hike in the desert.

Comment: Heh - don't ever come camping in the UK. Rain is the natural state :-)

Comment: Come on, one can sleep soo well hearing this sound! Also because there is nothing better to do. Our skiing teacher called this beautiful time in German: Kindermachenzeit :-))

Comment: Come on buddy....that is the sweetest sound ever :)

Comment: Raindrops keep falling on my tent... :-)

Comment: Having attempted to sleep in a torrential rain storm where you can't actually talk to the person next to you I know what you mean!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To me it's one of those sounds that can be soothing initially, but start to grate on you after hearing it for hours. You could try [ear plugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earplug#Hearing_protection). I don't wear them because I like being able to hear my surroundings, but I often see people camping with mp3 players, so not everyone appears to feel the need to be aware of their surroundings!

Comment: It depends where I am - if I'm in the middle of a campsite, I'm less inclined to listen to my surroundings than in the middle of Dartmoor for instance ;)

Comment: I must be paranoid. I have trouble listening to an mp3 player even around town.

Comment: Well, if I felt there was any danger with not hearing my surroundings then the ear plugs would go out the window!

Answer (score 9):

I usually throw a tarp above my tent. (an additional tarp, not the one that comes with most modern tents).  I find that it usually muffles the sound of the rain.  You will definitely still hear but not as intense.  They are relatively cheap too ($15+ CDN).

Comment: ...wouldn't there be the sound of the rain on the tarp?

Comment: @HartleyBrody Umm, yes? like I said?

Comment: Ahh yes, missed that bit :) I feel like a plastic tarp would be louder than a nylon rain fly though. But if it's worked for you, that's awesome!

Comment: I think the key is to tie off the tarp a couple feet above your tent. This will create another sound barrier and should muffle the sound of the drops considerably versus them hitting the tent itself.

Comment: @HartleyBrody :D Don't get me wrong if it is not rigged correctly it totally could be louder, usually there is a fair amount of space between my tarp and the tent, as in I can usually stand up comfortably under my tarp.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple exactly what I was typing, thank you :)

Comment: @TimothyStrimple So an even better solution would be to use two or even more tarps?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I think you'll benefit more from a larger distance between your tent and the suspended tarp. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would throw some type of foliage over the tent, to "break" the fall of the rain... so long as your tent is strong enough to support the weight!

Comment: Even better if you tie off another tarp or fly sheet above your main tent, and layer or tie some branches/foliage to that top layer.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes just choosing the location of your tent can make a huge difference in the amount of rain it receives. For example, you can protect it by placing it under thick foliage, or near a cliff if the wind is in the right direction.

Comment: Under foliage would just prolong the problem - drips from the foliage would continue after the rain has stopped.

Comment: The time that individual raindrops are falling may be longer, but the the intensity can often be significantly less.  So it all depends on what you are willing to put up with.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you just can't stand the sound of nature, an mp3 player or other source of noise that you CAN stand may work.